Infobar shows on all chrome windows when calling chrome.debugger.attach() API
I am encountring a behavior where attaching a debugger to specific tab using debugger.attach causes the info message to be attached to all open chrome tabs (i.e {{extensionName}} started debugging this browser) and not only to the specified tab, I didn't manage to find any information about it.
Is this a new beahvior?
Is there a way to avoid it?
I think it started 2 monthes ago, and now I wanted to fix it as I thought its a regression bug on my end- after creating a minimal repro case, I concluded it's not related to my code

This is the intended behavior, Chrome always did it, and people complained for years.

@wOxxOm Thank you! it's interesting as I and my co-workers do not recall this behavior, and we noticed it around 2 months ago
I suspected it to be an intended behavior, do you know anything about Chrome's intentions to correct this behavior? I didn't see any open issues from users on this matter

Judging by this report the warning shouldn't be shown for policy-installed extensions. For normal extensions the warning has always been shown and chromium developers always confirmed it's intentional when the users complained. Some chromium-based browsers behave differently, btw. There's also a command line switch to hide it.
